# Has anyone else but me noticed that The Free Dictionary has become sticky?

Tags: discussion

For maybe a month now, it takes too long to backpedal from TFD to the previous url.  Is this my computer, or is this happening to other people too?   I noticed this at about the same time I noticed that TFD was cluttered with ads.  I suppose the ads work, statistically, but I will try to avoid TFD because I am tired of getting stuck on the site when I want to move back and then on.

Comment: I notice no especial delays, but I use Ublock Origin. (I'd rather not disable it and risk compromising my privacy and contracting viruses through malicious or hijacked ads.)

Comment: I also use ad blocking filters, and have noticed no problems returning to previous URLs. TFD does periodically tweak their page code in unproductive or destructive ways, but the problems are usually fixed fairly promptly.

Comment: It is a fairly common practice on many "reference" web sites for the page to "stack up" several copies of itself such that you have to hit "Back" several times on your browser to exit.  Presumably this is so you will linger on the page longer and see more ads.  On Firefox the solution to this is to press and hold the "Back" button so that you get the drop-down list of "stacked" sites, then pick the one you were in before you first entered the problem site.  I assume that other browsers operate in a similar fashion.